# Labeling a Feature Class - how to force the label to use a particular field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I am trying to make a map with the voter blocks labeled.  The label command uses the county identifier field.  Can I force it to label with the voting block field?[image]

Comment: Hi @user30728! If you feel that I've answered you question please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Right click your feature class and choose **Properties...**

[image: 1]

Browse to the Labels tab. "Label features in this layer" should already be checked. If it isn't, check it. Choose your voting block field in the "Label Field" Text string box.

[image]

Comment: Good job on the screen captures!